# Download Excel in JavaScript from servlet response

Tags: javascript, java, excel, spring, apache-poi

I've seen many similar questions elsewhere, but have not been able to resolve this problem.

I want to download an Excel document in my application using Apache POI (3.17). I am generating the document in a Spring service then passing this as a response back to the JavaScript client to be downloaded. However, the file is corrupted because the "file format or file extension is not valid".

Spring service:

```
final Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
final Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test");

Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
if (row == null)
{
    row = sheet.createRow(1);
}

Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
if (cell == null)
{
    cell = row.createCell(0);
}

cell.setCellValue("Testing123");

final ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(outByteStream);
outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
outByteStream.flush();
outByteStream.close();
workbook.close();
```

Servlet:

```
final ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(
                this.downloadService.downloadExcel(request, response, baseRequest));

final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + resource.getFilename());

return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
        .body(resource);
```

JavaScript client:

```
var contentTypeHeader = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
var blob = new Blob([result],{type: contentTypeHeader});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = filename;
link.click();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out actually. I found this solution which fixed the issue:

[Getting corrupted file while exporting .xls file using java/javascript and apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472768/getting-corrupted-file-while-exporting-xls-file-using-java-javascript-and-apach)

I needed to encode the file as a string in my servlet, which was then passed to the client and decoded to a Blob.